# XSD element restricted with attribute

Tags: attributes, xsd, element, restriction

Hi I have problem with schema, I try to create restricted element with attribute like this:

```
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

      <xs:simpleType name="turn">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedShort">
          <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
          <xs:maxInclusive value="360"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>

      <xs:element name = "TURN_LEFT" type="turn" nillable="false">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:unsignedShort">
              <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="description" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:element name = "FORWARD" nillable="false">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:unsignedShort">
              <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="description" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

    </xs:schema>
```

Error description on open tag of TURN_LEFT "type attribute can not be present together with the element of simpleType or complexType".

How to use restriction with attribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears that element "turn" is used by TURN_LEFT in the schema . 
However there are two explicit declarations of the same element which are not needed .
You can try the below correction:

```
<xs:element name = "TURN_LEFT" type="turn" nillable="false">
    <!-- Commented TURN_LEFT declaration -->
    <!--<xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:unsignedShort">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="description" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>-->
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="turn">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedShort">
        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="360"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>



<xs:element name = "FORWARD" nillable="false">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:unsignedShort">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="description" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have in an element both a *type* attribute and a *complexType* (or simpleType) child.

TURN_LEFT could be a element of type *turn* (attribute *type="turn"*), OR TURN_LEFT should be a element of type the complexType defined inside the element.

Look at this simple examaple:

```
<xs:element name="myElement" type="xs:boolean">
    <xs:restriction base="float">
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:element>
```

If you define an element like that the XML Schema its not correct because is ambigous (how do we know if *myElement* its of boolean type or float type if you have defined both times the type?).

I think this is what you want to do:

```
  <xs:element name = "TURN_LEFT" nillable="false">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="turn">
          <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="description" use="optional"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

The base (the type you are extending) its the *turn* type.
This will validate this element:

```
<TURN_LEFT description="cool">12</TURN_LEFT>
```